# .NET Code first migration for SQL: adding migration to an existing database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I was put on a C# project that **already has an SQL database on azure** and asked to implement an **automatic code first migration system**.

We have a db on azure, but I will have to use a localhost test db for this purpose.

In the Web.config there was already a mechanism to choose between azure's or the local db using:

```
<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="..." .. />
```

I followed the following [tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2012/11/13/enable-automatic-code-first-migrations-on-sql-database-in-azure.aspx) step by step but now when I run the application i get the following error:

> No service registered for type 'ITableControllerConfigProvider'. Please Ensure That the dependency resolve Has Been Correctly configured.

Error is triggered by **WebApiConfig.cs** at line 20:

```
// Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
```

I found [this solution online](https://trompetin17.wordpress.com/2014/10/04/fix-no-service-registered-for-type-itablecontrollerconfigprovider-please-ensure-that-the-dependency-resolver-has-been-configured-correctly/) but it didn't work. I added the dependentAssembly for **System.Web.Http** but still get the same error.

What is the reason behind this error and what is the best approach to handle it?

## UPDATE

Thanks to the feedback given, I was able to fix it. For anyone with the same scenario here is what I was missing:

- Wrong initializer context and order in **Global.asx.cs under Application_Start()**

  ```
   // This must be first in code
   WebApiConfig.Register();
   // Context: get it from Configuration.cs
   app.Models.MobileServiceContext myDbContext = new app.Models.MobileServiceContext();
   // Configuration() should come from your app
   Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<app.Models.MobileServiceContext, Configuration>());
   myDbContext.Database.Initialize(false);
  ```
- Wrong local connection string:
  Since we had a database the connection string was not pointing to the same version number of the one created by migration.
  In **Web.config**

  ```
  <add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString=".....VERSION_NB";.../>
  ```

  Version number must point to the one created by migration.

## UPDATE 2

I updated my migration mechanism, inspired by the following [tutorial.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations.md)

Comment: Update 2 tutorial link is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be sure why your code is throwing that error. There are only three things that I think might be the cause of the problem.

1. Your config is not fully initialised. Try

   config.EnsureInitialized()
2. You are using a dependency inject framework like Ninject, and the dependency resolver has not been set. Try

   config.DependencyResolver = 
           new NinjectResolver(kernel)

Also check the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.tables.itablecontrollerconfigprovider.aspx

I think you have to register an implementation of ITableControllerConfigProvider as the config's dependency resolver.

3. You could be missing an assembly

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I think number 3 was my case I will post how I fixed it in an update above.